# How to extract values from JSONObject in android

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-json

1.I am having json object like this how can i get the access to all values in android
2.before anyone down voting that i want to say i have searched stackoverflow for similar examples but those examples contains JSONObject and then JSONArray 
3.Here in my case everything is JSONObject so i'm little bit confused

```
{
"1":
{"sno":"10","latitude":"31.249441437085455","longitude":"75.70003598928452"},

"2":
{"sno":"11","latitude":"31.249398442090207","longitude":"75.70003397762775"}
}
```

**This is how i made it to JSONObject**

1.Below code returned me output like that which is all JSONObject
2.Is there any way to make "1" and "2" as JSONArray ?

```
$select_rows = "select sno,latitude,longitude from activities where username='$username'";
if ($result = mysql_query($select_rows)) {

$num_of_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);
$num_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

 $i = 0;

    $j = 1;

    while ($retrieved = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_of_fields; $i++) {

            $field_name = mysql_field_name($result, $i);

            $object[$j][$field_name] = $retrieved[$field_name];
        }
        $j++;
    }
    echo json_encode($object);
}
```

Comment: The only way to parse all the values in a `JSONObject` is knowing the tags for all items. You would be better off using an array in your json rather than naming them 1, 2, etc.

Comment: @dcharms i have elaborated how i would got that output.. can you please suggest me how to make JSONArray if you have any idea.. otherwise thanks for your efforts...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope this may help you

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(result);

            jsonObject=jsonObject.getJSONObject("1");

            Double lat=jsonObject.getDouble("latitude");




            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),""+ lat, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 5):

Better create a valid `JSONArray` to make things easier. When you create the `JSON` string , don't append the index. I believe your are reading the data from sqlite and generating the `JSON` string.

Also change the outer `{` (curly brace) to [ (square bracket) to represent as `Array` element. So your json string will be like this

```
[
{
    "sno": "10",
    "latitude": "31.249441437085455",
    "longitude": "75.70003598928452"
},
{
    "sno": "11",
    "latitude": "31.249398442090207",
    "longitude": "75.70003397762775"
}
]
```

Then , you can simply get its as `JSONArray`

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
```

And then read each element in array item

```
 for(int index = 0;index < jsonArray.length(); index++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);
 }
```

Comment: Hi can you please look at this post.. I am getting no response.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319920/marker-is-not-adding-properly-while-add-through-for-loop

Answer (score 1):

To get one of your inner JSONObject elements, you'll need to get it from the outer one using getJSONObject(String key).

Sample code:

```
JSONObject item1 = myJson.getJSONObject("1");
//item1 now contains {sno:10,latitude:31.2...etc}
//now you can get the individual values out of the resulting JSON Object
//for example, getting the latitude
double lat = item1.getDouble("latitude");
```